# How to use BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH for execting a function for each in the sequence?

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, macros, preprocessor

I intend to use BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH to run a function for all variables of a sequence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>


#define SEQ (w)(x)(y)(z)
#define MACRO(r, data, elem) foo(#elem);

using namespace std;


void foo(string a) {
  cout << a << endl;
}


int main(){


  BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MACRO, ,SEQ) ;


  return 0 ;
}
```

The expected output is like:

```
w
x
y
z
```

, while the actual result is:

```
BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD((w)(x)(y)(z))
BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD((x)(y)(z))
BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD((y)(z))
BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD((z))
```

I don't know what happens to the expansion. I am thinking BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH clause is expanded into

```
MACRO(r, ,w) MACRO(r, ,x) MACRO(r, ,y) MACRO(r, ,z)
```

and MACRO(r, ,w) is expanded into `foo("w");` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD((a)(b)(c))` is a macro to get the head of a preprocessor sequence and would expand to `a`. But `#elem` prevents that macro from being expanded.

Use [`BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/stringize.html) to expand the macro as well:

```cpp
#define MACRO(r, data, elem) foo(BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem));
```